# PHP mysql insert text

Tags: php, mysql, text

My Code:

```
function sendMessage($client, $owner, $topic, $message, $send, $alliance, $player, $coor, $report) {
            $time = time();
    $q = "INSERT INTO " . TB_PREFIX . "mdata values (0,$client,$owner,'$topic',\"$message\",0,0,$send,$time,0,0,$alliance,$player,$coor,$report)";
    return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}
```

When i writing message there is no problem. But if i send to mysql this -> ' transform to this -> /'

' -> /'

I need code for solve it.. Please help me.

Comment: You mean you need to escape the quotes? You need to be using `mysql_real_escape_string()` on _all_ of those string variables, and verify that the numeric ones are actually numeric values. The strings must be quoted in the query as you have with `'$topic'` after they have been escaped.

Comment: The _real_ solution though is to start using an API which supports prepared statements, like PDO or MySQLi, in which the escaping is handled for you.

Comment: I cant use pdo or mysqli because my script fully mysql. I need easy code. Who can write it?

Comment: You misunderstand me - the best solution is to convert the whole script while you are working on it now. The `mysql_*()` extension will be deprecated in the next major PHP version, and will eventually cease to work

Comment: But what you need here is `$message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);` and place it as `'$message'` in the query `VALUES ()` list.  Do this for _all_ the string parameters.

Comment: Moving from mysql_ to mysqli_ isn't so hard. Now's the time to do it!

Comment: Michael can you prepare and apply to my code, please? I cant do it:(

Comment: magic_quote_gpc is on in your system. Change it to off if possible.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  function sendMessage($client, $owner, $topic, $message, $send, $alliance, $player, $coor, $report) {

   $client = mysql_real_escape_string($client);
    $owner = mysql_real_escape_string($owner);
    $topic = htmlentities($topic);
  $message = htmlentities($message);
     $send = mysql_real_escape_string($send);
 $alliance = mysql_real_escape_string($alliance);
   $player = mysql_real_escape_string($player);
     $coor = mysql_real_escape_string($coor);
   $report = mysql_real_escape_string($report);

        $time = time();

    $q = "INSERT INTO " . TB_PREFIX . "mdata values (0,'$client','$owner','$topic','$message',0,0,'$send','$time',0,0,'$alliance','$player','$coor','$report')";
   return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
   }
```

Comment: what is the variable which make this ?? and can you share how is defined the variable who make this thing ?

Comment: is it the `$message` variable who transforme this ??

Comment: Message and topic .. ' transform to \' .. But other special characters working.. And if i delete \ on phpmyadmin it working. I cant understand how be this..

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what the others have commented you should use PDO, but just use `mysql_real_escape_string` when passing `varchar` or other string type fields.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO " . TB_PREFIX . "mdata values (0,$client,$owner,
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($topic) . "',
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($message) . "',
    0,0,$send,$time,0,0,$alliance,
    $player,$coor,$report)";
```

Comment: You'll need to show your table definition and the expected values of those variables for further help